# Nextjs & Apollo: Attach cookie to Apollo Client in getInitialProps server side

Tags: next.js, apollo

So I understand that I can access my cookies server side using ctx.req.headers.cookie, but I'm not sure how to send that cookie to my GraphQL endpoint with Apollo Client.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know your cookies's name that you would like to be sent? And why Apollo need your cookie to do what?

Comment: I wanted to send the cookie to my graphql server which authenticates the user with a JWT I store in an HTTP only cookie. It would automatically send this cookie when it sends in client side, just not the first time in server, so i have to manually attach the cookie.

Comment: Great. A small improvement is not to send all the cookies, just send the cookie's key/value that server requires for authentication

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way I can suggest is using `Apollo HTTP Link's context` (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/http/#passing-context-per-query)

If you monitor common HTTP requests on websites, you may notice the `cookie` header is set in the request headers, represent the cookies sent.

So you can `send cookies` to Apollo by setting the same `cookie` in Apollo HTTP client's headers

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  gql,
  createHttpLink
} from "@apollo/client";


const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: createHttpLink({ uri: "https://myserver.com" })
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });

// Pass the cookie header into context when using ApolloClient
const cookie = 'mycookie1=myvalue1; mycookie2=myvalue2';
client.query({
      fetchPolicy: "cache-first",
      context: {
        headers: {
          cookie
        }
      },
      query: gql``
});
```

Or using the low-level Apollo Link: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-context/#overview

Comment: Hi, how can you get the existing cookies to set into query context?

Comment: Hi, you can use Javascript `document.cookie` if you have access on the clients side.
If you are on server side, maybe you should catch headers, cookies from the `request` object.